# "That soon parts will not exist"

Tags: meaning

Somebody please explain this sentence to me. I found this while reading about **[Pollution and the Environment](http://txtshr.com/physics/23833/index.html?page=3)**

> **Important definitions** 
>   People are more worried about the environment (= the air, water, and land around us) as a result of the harmful (= dangerous/damaging) effects of human activity. Some of these activities cause pollution (= dirty air, land and water) and some are destroying the environment (= damaging it so badly that **soon parts will not exist**). 
>   Here are some of the problems: the ozone layer; global warming; acid rain.

Comment: Is the parenthetical part of the quotation? (It is not grammatical.)

Comment: Please tell us more about where you found the sentence you would like to see explained, and why you're confused. More info available [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439).

Comment: @J.R. Oops! I took a stab at it.

Comment: If you can explain more what you are confused about, we may be able to reopen the question and help you. Is it "soon parts" that is the problem?

Comment: I've edited my question. Sorry for the typos mistake.

Comment: @J.R. Well, I edited the question. The heading is **important definitions** and into the bracket are the explanations of the words. The OP's phrase in concern is nothing but explaining the word **destroying** telling that it's damaging so badly that soon parts (it's associated with) won't exist. I think this can be also put as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess that "is" in your quotation was meant to be "it".

I believe the equivalence denoted by '=' is between these two phrases:

> 1. . . . destroying the environment . . .
> 2. . . . damaging i[t] so badly that soon parts will not exist.

At first glance, neither phrase seems possible. "Environment", according to Google, means:

> 1. the surroundings or conditions in which a person, animal, or plant lives or operates.
> 2. the natural world, as a whole or in a particular geographical area, esp. as affected by human activity.
>    <sub>Source: [Oxford Dictionaries, definition of "environment"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/environment)</sub>

Strictly speaking, neither the "surroundings" nor "the natural world" could be destroyed, especially not to the point of non-existence, but the "conditions in which" life persists (the things life requires—or, specifically, the things the life of an organism adapted to said things requires) might no longer exist.

Wikipedia provides a little clearer assistance in this matter:

> The term "environment" can refer to different concepts, but is often used as a short form for "the biophysical environment."
> <sub>Source: [Wikipedia, Environment (biophysical)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_(biophysical))</sub>

> The biophysical environment is the biotic and abiotic surrounding of an organism or population, **and includes the factors that have an influence [o]n their survival, development and evolution.**
> <sub>Source: [Wikipedia, Environment (biophysical)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_(biophysical))</sub>

Without further context, I'd assume we were talking about humans. That is to say **"environment"** in this case refers to **the physical conditions that "have an influence [on human] survival, [etc.]."**

With this in mind, the quotation could be glossed thus:

> [. . .] destroying the environment = damaging **i[t]<sup>1</sup> so badly<sup>2</sup>** that soon parts **will not exist.<sup>3</sup>**
>
> <sup>**1**</sup> constituent physical aspects of the environment as defined above
> <sup>**2**</sup> to such an extreme, detrimental degree
> <sup>**3**</sup> will no longer act as constituents of the aforementioned environment

This means that some parts of the environment (trees that provide us with the oxygen we breathe, for example) are being damaged by "these activities" ([deforestation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deforestation), for example) to the point that they are destroyed and will "soon" no longer be in the area or contributing to our survival.

Comment: Thank you Tyler. This is very informative and instructive.but if I may I want to nitpick about giving credit to Google. it's not Googles dictionary it's oxfords dictionary. Thank you again.

Comment: @GATA noted. I'll update the attribution when I'm not on my phone.

Comment: Thank you Tyler, i edited my post. Can you tell me what 's the usage of "that" in the sentence ?. I thought it should be "damaging it so badly that soon (some of) its parts will not exist".

Comment: @user2747502 In this example *that* is a subordinator, indicating that the following text is a finite subordinate clause.  It appears here in the correlative construction ***so A that B***, which indicates that A is true to a such a great extent that B is true as well.